# Location of .appref-ms file in click once deployment

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce

I have a clickonce application that can be available either online or offline.
I would like to know how to determine the location of the .appref-ms file accurately.
IS it always at the same location?
Thanks, I apologize if this seems like a noob question, I am new to click once deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortcut is always on the start menu. In the options dialog, whatever you set the publishing company to is used for teh folder on the start menu. Whatever you set the product name to is used for the name of hte icon on the start menu. As long as you don't change those two things, the ClickOnce app's shortcut will always show up in the same place.

Try this to set the path to the shortcut:

> string.Concat(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs),
>   "\", company, "\", description, ".appref-ms");

where company is the publishing company from the options dialog, and description is the product name.